# Can I display hotlinked images in a database?

Tags: php, mysql, database, hotlinking

I was wondering if it's possible to display an image from a site like imageshack on my website using a data base, for example, I use the URL some where in the database, and when I display that data, the picture is displayed as well.

Is it possible to do this and if so, how should I go about doing it?

Comment: Are you familiar with the HTML `<img />` tag?

Comment: Have you actually tried to do this?  That would give you the answer.

Comment: eggyal: I'm asking if I can display it through mysql database, I already know how to make it appear through html

Comment: Well, if you know how to do it through HTML, then all you need is for your PHP to output precisely that.  How PHP constructs the HTML, using an underlying database or otherwise, will have no bearing: the same HTML will be output to the browser and the browser will render the image accordingly.

Comment: it is theoretically possible to do, if you scrape pages and store the url to the image in a database, then just pull it out with a query and use something like... echo "<img src='".$row['image_url']."' />";

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The other commenters here are correct. Simply store the  tags with the correct link in your database as text.

You can store it, you can't, however, display it in your database as the database only holds data. This would require another language such as Java, Python, PHP or any language with a database accessor class.

Comment: Rather than storing markup in the database layer, I'd recommend storing the data (i.e., the URL) and generating the markup in the presentation layer.

Comment: Yes, yes that thing you said, eggyal. I was just trying to simplify it a bit.

Comment: One thing. Even if you put the items into the database it's a good idea to strip the tags for security. echo '<img src="'.strip_tags($imageURL).'" />';